# Am I using dependencies compiled against system packages?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Following a [recent announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-updates-to-the-aws-lambda-execution-environment/) by AWS that they are updating the AWS Lambda Execution Environment, I'm trying to understand some terminology that they used. It appears that if I'm not using any 'dependencies compiled against a system package' then I need not take action.

I'm not entirely sure what they are referring to though. For example, I have created a [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) (effectively just a .zip folder with my code in it) in order to include packages that are not provided in the Python Lambda environment. To do this I ran the following command before zipping:

```
pip3 install requests -t /path/to/folder
```

This created a bunch of files and folders in my Python folder (`/path/to/folder`) that the 'requests' package needs. I then zipped and uploaded this to Lambda. I've used a few more packages like 'yaml', 'json', 'bson', 'socket', 'ssl' etc.

What constitutes a dependency compiled against a system package and how would I know whether I'm using one?